# Use local sourcemap with external sources

Tags: source-maps

I have production website with no sourcemaps, and I have sourmaps locally matching production compiled + minified coffee.

Is there any way to ask browser's developer tools to use this (local) sourcemap *without* actually uploading it to server and adding as a sourceMappingURL comment or http header?

Answer (score 0):

There is: Specify

```
 //# sourceMappingURL=http://localhost/xxx.js.map
```

as the last line of your script and have a local web server (behind a foirewall) supplying it.

Works fine for me.